Reboot and select proper boot device SSD error EVERY TIME SSD is disconnected
While I have figured out how to do this on a one-time basis, the issue happened again. So the question remains - why, whenever I unplug the SSD from the SATA port on the AAEON EMB-BT1 itx board, does it then refuse to boot and give this error?
My operating system is Debian Linux and I cannot be reinstalling grub-efi every time I swap SSDs.
These are my partitions, could the fact that the EFI system begins at 2048 instead of 0 have something to do with it? Yet this is the way the Debian partition manager configured it.

The following are the states of the disks after going through the reinstall grub-efi process:


Evidently the Boot0001* option does not work, and the Boot0000* debian entry gets wiped when I disconnect the SSD from the motherboard. I just do not understand why or how.
EDIT: When I boot there is also an ACPI Bus Error

Apparently your system firmware will automatically delete any UEFI NVRAM boot entries that refer to disks that are no longer accessible. That helps avoid the possibility of the UEFI NVRAM becoming full, but can be a pain if you swap boot disks often. Unfortunately there is probably nothing you can do to change this firmware behavior.
Instead, you can install a second copy of the UEFI GRUB bootloader to the removable media/fallback path on the EFI System Partition. That should help the firmware to auto-detect the disk as bootable.
You can do this with:
sudo grub-install --force-extra-removable /dev/sda

This will result a second copy of the bootloader at /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.efi, which is the path the firmware looks for when booting on removable media (on the x64 hardware architecture), or when the applicable UEFI NVRAM boot entry for the installed OS has been lost.
If you do this to all your system SSDs, it should minimize the effort involved in swapping SSDs. Windows 10 and 11 will automatically set up a copy of their UEFI bootmanager to this path by default, so if one of your boot SSDs contains Windows, you should not need to do anything special for it.
The fact that your EFI System Partition starts at block #2048 is normal - unlike the old MBR partition table that was just 64 bytes in size, the GPT partition table will occupy at least 33 512-byte sectors, and the modern standard is to set up partition limits at exact multiples of 1 MiB for data alignment reasons - this avoids performance degradation on SSDs and some SANs that internally use much larger disk blocks.

Really interesting - I should like to read more about the system firmware and even perhaps see the code. But I will try this and hopefully it will fix the problem.

Unfortunately the actual UEFI firmware in your system is most likely proprietary, but the TianoCore project is an open-source implementation. The specifications for UEFI firmware are also available for free at uefi.org. Roderick W. Smith's rEFInd boot manager documentation also includes a lot of practical information on various quirks of UEFI implementations, and of living with UEFI in general.

Unplugging a disk device that is in use is very likely to corrupt data on the disk.  For best results, unmount the disk before unplugging.
Additionally, SATA only partially supports hot unplugging devices.
If the device is in a hot swap slot with physical rails, it likely is safe.  But if it just has a cable connected to it without any guides, then every time you unplug or plug in the drive while power is on, there is a chance of damaging the drive electronics.
Additionally, if you plug a drive in after BIOS has initialized, it may not detect the drive as bootable and will not have it in its boot list; rebooting or power cycling may fix this.   Also, if you are using EFI mode, when the bootloader is installed, an entry is added to the bios EFI boot list, and if the drive is not online when bios inititalizes, it may delete boot entries associated with the drive.
If the drive is not booting, the following options may be available:

Some bios's allow manually adding EFI entries
Some bios's allow you to manually select detected efi entries for drives that are not on the list through a generated boot menu
From the OS, the efibootmgr tool can add an entry to bios
Tools like rEFInd can scan all disks for bootable EFI executables

